# Are Symbian native functions supported in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, symbian

I am little confused on this. I would like to use some native functions of Symbian in my Phonegap app, mainly Camera functions. [On official Phonegap doc site for Camera](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html), there is no mentioning of Symbian beeing supported platform. There are just Android, iPhone and Blackberry.

But if I look inside downloaded Phonegap package (version 1.0) there are javascript files in Symbian folder where it looks like the support for Camera is implemented. But I am confused why Symbian is not listed in Supported platforms in documentation.

Unfortunately, I don't have a Symbian phone to test it out. Can someone shed some light at this issue ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whome, like me, is reading right now (July 2015) is sad but useful to know that Cordova removed Symbian support On October 15th, 2014.

Source: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/10/01/upcoming-deprecations/